# Representation of harmonic function as a series

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let, $u:D\to\mathbb{C}$ is a harmonic function then how to show that $u(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n z^n + \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}b_n\bar{z}^n$.
(D be the unit disk).

Comment: WLOG, you can assume $u$ is continuous up to the boundary, then consider the Fourier series of $u$ on $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: @Landau without Fourier series can't be it done?I don't know much these type of thing,or can you explained this in a bit details.

Answer (score 4):

Let us quickly show that $u$ decomposes into a holomorphic and antiholomorphic function.
Assume that $u=f+ig$.
Since $f$ is harmonic and $D$ is simply connected, it has a harmonic conjugate $g_c$ such that $f+ig_c$ is holomorphic.
Furthermore, $g$ has also a harmonic conjugate such that $f_c+ig$ is holomorphic.
Then the functions
$$
F=\frac{f+f_c}{2}+i\frac{g+g_c}{2}    \\
\bar{G}=\frac{f-f_c}{2}-i\frac{g_c-g}{2}
$$
are holomorphic and antiholomorphic, respectively. Also we have $u=F+\bar{G}$ and a holomorphic function can be written as a power series in $z$, while an antiholomorphic function can be written as a power series in $\bar{z}$.

Comment: $u=F+\bar{G}$ ??

Comment: Yeah. :-) Thanks.